# Expo/Firebase: Image chosen from camera roll uploading as octet-stream instead of .jpg

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, expo, react-native-image-picker

I've been having trouble viewing the image files I've uploaded to firebase and just noticed the issue is with the file type in firebase.

[image]

Two files in my firebase storage console. One uploaded from my IOS simulator (octet-stream) and the other uploaded directly into the console from the browser which uploads properly and is viewable.

Here are my select and upload functions:

```
_selectPhoto = async () => {

    const status = await getPermission(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (status) {
      let imageName = "pic"
      const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync(options);
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        Animated.timing(this.animatedWidth, {
          toValue: 600,
          duration: 15000
      }).start()
        this.uploadImage(result.uri, imageName)
        .then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')
        })        
        .catch((error) => {
          Alert.alert('Must Sign In');
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
          console.log(error);

        })
      }
    }


  };


uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(''images/'+user.displayName+'/'+imageName+'.jpg'');

    const snapshot = await storageRef.put(blob);
    blob.close();
    snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
      console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
      user.updateProfile({
        photoURL: downloadURL.toString(),
        }).then(function() {
            console.log('saved photo')

        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('failed photo')

        });

    });

}
```

When I get the link in my console, it also has the media&token:

> ... .appspot.com/o/profile-pic.jpg?alt=media&token=56eb9c36-b5cd-4dbb-bec1-3ea5c3a74bdd

If I CMD+Click in VS Code I receive an error:

```
{
  error: {
    code: 400,
    message: "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}
```

So naturally, when I put that link in the browser it downloads a file with that name but says:

> The file “pic.jpg” could not be opened. 
>   It may be damaged or use a
>   file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.

Maybe it could be something with mediaTypes, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it.

> mediaTypes : String -- Choose what type of media to pick. Usage:
>   ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions., where  is one of: Images,
>   Videos,  All.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've been fighting with this same issue for the past few days. I was finally able get images to upload and render as expected by following the [Firebase Upload example in the Expo repo](https://github.com/expo/firebase-storage-upload-example/blob/master/App.js). I don't fully understand why it works, but it seems like Firebase doesn't like the blob that's generated by

`const blob = await response.blob();`

Try replacing the above with:

```
const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
    };
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });
```